# What is the difference between IEnumerable and ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, oop

What is the difference between `IEnumerable` & `ObservableCollection` in C#?

For example, in this piece of code:

```
public class RecipeDataItem
{        
    public RecipeDataItem(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String description, String imagePath, String tileImagePath, int prepTime, String directions, IEnumerable<string> ingredients)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ImagePath = imagePath;
        this.TileImagePath = tileImagePath;
        this.PrepTime = prepTime;
        this.Directions = directions;
        this.Ingredients = new ObservableCollection<string>(ingredients);
    }

    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
    public string TileImagePath { get; set; }
    public int PrepTime { get; set; }
    public string Directions { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Ingredients { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

We are defining a variable `Ingredients`, which is a `ObservableCollection` of strings, & then we are defining a variable in the parameterized constructor `ingredients` which is an `IEnumerable` of strings.

Comment: You can't compare them. One is an interface, one is an class... And by the way `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: Your question _"what's the difference"_ doesn't seem to make sense. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: An `IEnumerable` is typically something you can enumerate - such as collections of items or generators. An `ObservableCollection` is a list that raises events when it's being modified. One is abstract and broad, the other concrete and specific. Note that `ObservableCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, among other interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all `IEnumerable<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` are something that you can't even compare to each other. The main reason is that `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface (all the interfaces in .NET framework have a name that starts with `I`, like `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`) and `ObservableCollection<T>` is a collection class, that implements indeed the interface `IEnumerable<T>`.

An interface, like `IEnumerable<T>`, is something abstract in which you can declare just the signature of methods for example, but you cannot implement their logic. The class that implements an interface will implement the logic of all the methods existing in the interface. Usually, a collection like `IEnumerable<string> results` is returned from a public method of a service or application, in order to enumerate it later using a `foreach` loop. Moreover, this collection has a [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and for this reason it's very useful whenever the collection contains many items, but it should be used carefully. Some of the collection classes that implements this interface are `ObservableCollection<T>`, `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

`ObservableCollection<T>` is a collection class that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Moreover, it is a a special collection, because it raises events whenever the collection itself is changed, for example when some items are added or removed. It's mostly used in WPF applications.

Answer (score 1):

An `IEnumerable` is a list of items that you can enumerate, i.e., that you can loop through in one direction, from first to last element.

An observable collection implements the interfaces `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It is a list that raises events whenever the contents change (an item is added, removed) or a property has changed.

`IEnumerable` is enough if you just want to iterate over the contents; if you need access to any element at any moment, it's better to use a stronger implementation such as a List. `IEnumerable` is the "weakest" of the collection interfaces, but often enough.

Comment: `IEnumerable` isn't a list, it is an interface. A list is an implementation detail.

Comment: I didn't say `IEnumerable` is a list. I said **an** `IEnumerable` is a list of items that you can enumerate.